# Java Swing Shift+F10 Accessibility

Tags: java, swing

Per accessibility requirements, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> is supposed to open right-click context menus.

In Swing, one approach is to just add the key binding to every component you make. However, I've experimented with extending the EventQueue to handle all <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> presses. In particular, I've overridden dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) to convert <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> KeyEvents into right-click mousePresses:

```
protected void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent event) {
    if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {
        KeyEvent ev = (KeyEvent) event;
        if ((ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F10) && 
                    (ev.getModifiersEx() & InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK) > 0) {
            KeyboardFocusManager kfm = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
            Component comp = kfm.getFocusOwner();
            Point mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(mouse, comp);

            eventToDispatch = new MouseEvent(comp,
                            MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, ev.getWhen(), 0, mouse.x, mouse.y, 
                            1, true);
        }
   }
}
```

However, this prevents <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> from being able to close any JPopupMenus that get launched. Any idea if this solution is workable, or are there better ways to accomplish meeting this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        try {
          int dotPosition = textField.getCaretPosition();
          Rectangle popupLocation = textField
              .modelToView(dotPosition);
          popup.show(textField, popupLocation.x, popupLocation.y);
        } catch (BadLocationException badLocationException) {
          System.out.println("Oops");
        }
      }
    };
    KeyStroke keystroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10,
        InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK);
    textField.registerKeyboardAction(actionListener, keystroke,
        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
```

Comment: I already knew that I could register the keyboard action for each component. However, our app is large. As a result, there are many components that already handle mouse popup triggers. That's why I'm looking to do this by capturing all Shift+F10 presses in the EventQueue.