# Shift F9 and Shift F10 KeyStroke combination doesn't work on windows

Tags: java, swing

I have difficulty to fire a key action in swing JPanel using key combination **Shift+F9** and **Shift+F10**. It does not get fired up while working in windows but the same code works in Ubuntu without any problem. here is how I set the key combination on top of the JPanel window:

```
private void addKeyBinding(JComponent jc) {
        key = 112;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            jc.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key++, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, false), ("shift-F" + (i + 1)));
            final int j = i;
            jc.getActionMap().put(("shift-F" + (i + 1)), new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    System.out.println("key pressed");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

However the following code does not have any problem for keys Shift+F1 till Shift+F8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250466/java-swing-shiftf10-accessibility?rq=1

Comment: @whyn0t the solution doesn't work ~

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. I just used a JFrame with  a JPanel. You probably have some other component on the frame and the key bindings of that component is taking precedence. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem if  you need more help.